# Print N numbers from a txt file and order with simple bubble in c language

Tags: c

Print n numbers from a txt file and order with simple bubble in c language

I am stuck with my code I have to do an ordering of numbers stored in a .txt file (10,000,000) to be exact,
with a simple bubble and that is capable of receiving a parameter “n” that indicates the number of integers to order

I mean--> how many numbers do you want to order?

10

read 10 numbers from the txt file and order them

I have this, I hope and you can help me!

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubblesort(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;  i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);

        }
    }
}
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}


int main()
{
    int array[100000], i, size;
    printf("How many numbers you want to sort:  ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("numeros10millones.txt","rt");

    while((size=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
        printf("%d",size);
    }

    fclose(f);

    bubblesort(array, size);
    printf("\nSorted array is ");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d ", array[i]);
    return 0;

}`

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working? Sorting 10 million numbers with a bubble sort is bound to be painful and you won't be able to allocate that size of an array on the stack. You might start with a much smaller set of numbers to verify your code is working. Right now you're not even reading them from the file into the array.

Comment: I already tried my ordering and it works, what I can't do is read the numbers from the file and order them :(

Comment: Does it? `for (j = 0; j < size - i; j++)` is incorrect. Perhaps you meant `size - 1`? Try using `fscanf` to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fscanf`.
`fscanf` reads exactly what is in the file.
As pointed out by @RetiredNinja, trailing white spaces will be skipped, but not for ex. `\n`.

If your numbers in the file are separated by a space, you will read them as `"%d"`; if your numbers in the file are each on a different line, you will read them as `"%d\n"`; if your numbers have one letter between them, you will read them as `"%d %c"` (for ex. `A 0 B 1 C 2`); etc.

On success, `fscanf` returns the number of elements read (if you read `"%d"`, the return value will be 1; if you read `"%d %c"`, the return value will be 2; etc.).
While `scanf != EOF`, you can keep reading.
If `fscanf == EOf`, an error occurred or the end of the file has been reached.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void bubblesort(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;  i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);

        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i, size;
    printf("How many numbers you want to sort:  ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("numbers","r");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fscanf(f, "%d ", &array[i]);

    fclose(f);

    bubblesort(array, size);
    printf("\nSorted array is ");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d ", array[i]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

This will read a text file written in the following way:

```
0 4 5 7 1 8 3 2 9 6
```

Comment: `%d` in a `scanf` format string skips leading whitespace. Both of your assertions that you should add a space or newline after the `%d` in the format string are incorrect, and can lead to difficult to find bugs. In addition you should *always* check the return value from `scanf` to be sure it actually converted the correct number of items. If 20 is entered for `size` and there are only 10 numbers in the file the last 10 items of the allocated memory are uninitialized.